# Optimizing Kernel Density Bandwidth using Python

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, kernel-density

I am attempting to build a class that automatically determines the optimal bandwidth for a kernel density estimate. I am using the FFTKDE method of [KDEpy](https://kdepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for my purposes, since I am required to calculate this quantity very quickly. I am aware that there are the options of Scott's Rule, Silverman's Rule and Improved Sheather-Jones in KDEpy, but I am keen to directly optimise mysomething bandwidth.

I would like to calculate the Maximum likelihood cross-validation (MCLV) in order that I optimize it. However, my code is terribly slow, since I need to estimate the KDE for each data point in 20,000 data points, each iteration of the minimisation.

The equation I am attempting to optimize looks like this (see page 8, [here](https://jmlr.org/papers/volume17/14-540/14-540.pdf)):

[image]

My code for calculating this loss is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from KDEpy import FFTKDE 
from tqdm import tqdm
import time

def MLCV(data, bw):
   N = len(data)
   idx = np.ones(N, bool)
   logs = np.empty(N)
   for i in tqdm(range(N)):
     idx[i]=False
     x_kde, y_kde = FFTKDE(bw=bw).fit(data[idx]).evaluate(2**13)
     idx[i]=True
     logs[i] = np.sum(np.log(y_kde))

   MLCV = np.sum(logs)/N - np.log((N-1)*bw)
   return MLCV

data = np.random.normal(size=20000)
bw = 0.01
t0 = time.process_time()
mlcv = MLCV(data, bw)
t1 = time.process_time()
print("MLCV = {:3.3E}, Elapsed Time = {:3.3}s".format(mlcv, t1-t0))
```

Output:

```
MLCV = -1.077E+05, Elapsed Time = 46.3s
```

Can anyone suggest a means of making this faster/an alternative, quicker algorithm?

I have also considered simply minimising the negative log of the output, which I have seen elsewhere:

```
def L(data, bw):
    x_kde, y_kde = FFTKDE(bw=bw).fit(data).evaluate(2**13)
    return -np.sum(np.log(y_kde))
```

However, my intuition tells me neither method is the correct solution, since I cannot directly calculate the values for the actual data, only interpolate them, due to the FFT method requiring points to be on a grid.

Is there a loss that suits my needs? Can anyone suggest a better solution than I have come up with?

Comment: I do not understand why you have to run fit for each point in a for loop (maybe at least provide data in chunks?). And why keep track of evaluation at 2**13?

Comment: - 2**13 is some number of samples, and does not really effect the speed of the algorithm.

- This loss requires me to 'leave one out' for each fit, thus I am trying to achieve this; I am unsure of whether I am allowed to simply subsample a thousand points, say, and use this as an estimate. As for the for loop, I am merely trying to show my interpretation of the equation for the benefit of the answer.

Comment: But you are not doing "leave-one-out", what you are doing is "leave-all-but-one"